# What's the error in this SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have created this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM forum_question 
        LEFT JOIN forum_answer ON (
            forum_question.id = forum_answer.question_id) 
    ORDER BY a_datetime DESC GROUP BY forum_question.id;
```

Does anyone know the problem? forum_question and forum_answer and the column 'id' exist by the by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` clause should come first before `ORDER BY` clause. Try interchanging it,

```
GROUP BY forum_question.id
ORDER BY a_datetime DESC
```